# Displaying additional data below matrix

Tags: powerbi

I have a emails table which shows the date the email was sent in one column and the email message in another column:

[image]

I want to create a matrix which will display the month in the first column (1 row for each month. 12 rows in total) and then the number of emails sent for that month in the next column. I want the user to be able to click on the actual number in the second column and then the email messages for the emails sent in that month, to be displayed below the matrix table in a list that you can scroll through.

Something like this:

[image]

I have seen this done somewhere else before but unsure how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to power query and add the following step changing the source statement for your previos step.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Source", "Month", each Date.MonthName([Sent Date], "en-US"), type text)
```

That will create the month name column in case you dont have a date table.

Then create a table visual and drag both the month name column and the Message column with the count option.

Create a second table visual and drag the message column into it.

Now when a record is selected into the first table the second is filtered.

This is the expected result:

[image]